# Lumen IoC binding resolution spotty within phpunit tests

Tags: php, laravel-5, ioc-container, lumen

I've run into an issue with Lumen v5.0.10 that has me at my wits end. I'm designing an application largely using TDD with the bundled `phpunit` extensions. I'm basically getting a `BindingResolutionException` for "App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface". This is an interface in the directory *App\Contracts* which has an implementation in *App\Services* which is registered in the `AppServiceProvider` like so:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {

        // Owner manager
        $this->app->singleton(
            'App\Contracts\OwnerInteractionInterface',
            'App\Services\OwnerManager'
        );

        // Subscriber manager
        $this->app->singleton(
            'App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface', 
            'App\Services\SubscriberManager'
        );

//      dd($this->app->bound('App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface'));
    }
}
```

My frustration is that if I uncomment that last line in the function then it shows that `App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface` has been bound (and thus may be resolved).

I then have a controller which effectively looks like this

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $log)
    {
        $this->log = $log;
    } 


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
           if (/* Seems to come from owner */)
           {
               $owners = App::make('App\Contracts\OwnerInteractionInterface');
               return $owners->process($request);
           }

           if (/* Seems to come from subscriber */)
           {
               $subscribers = App::make('App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface');
               return $subscribers->process($request);
           }
    }
}
```

I use them in this way because I only want the relevant one instantiated (not both as would happen if I type-hinted them) and they also each have type hinted dependencies in their constructors.

The issue is that the route of the tests that needs `OwnerInteractionInterface` runs just fine but the one that needs `SubscriberInteractionInterface` does not. The implementations and interfaces are largely similar and as I showed before, they are both registered at the same time and I can confirm that `SubscriberInteractionInterface` is bound. In fact, if I put the line:

```
dd(App::bound('App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface'));
```

at the top of `index()` it returns **true**. The tests happen to be ordered such that the path that uses `OwnerInteractionInterface` runs first and it resolves fine and then the other test fails with a `BindingResolutionException`. However, if I omit other tests and run just that one, then everything goes smoothly. The tests are in different files and the only setup I do is to bind a mock for a third party API in place of an entirely different binding from those shown and none of that code touches these classes. This is done within a `setUp()` function and I make sure to call `parent::setUp()` within it.

What's going on here? Could it be that binding one concrete instance wipes non-concrete bindings from the `IoC`? Or is it that the default setup allows some influence to transfer over from one test to another?

I know I sorta have a workaround but the constraint of never running the full test-suite is annoying. Its starting to seem that testing would be easier if I just use the instance directly instead of resolving it from its interface.

Also, does anyone know a way to inspect the `IoC` for resolvable bindings?

Comment: It seems that others are encountering similar issues with unit testing in Laravel only they encounter them with Eloquent events as discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1181).

Comment: The issue seems to have something to do with how Lumen destroys and re-sets up the application instance in the `tearDown()` and  `setUp()` methods of `TestCase`. The first time works fine but something isn't quite right every other time. The issue can be observed with `OwnerInteractionInterface` as well in subsequent tests. For now a workaround is to only run **one** test at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further attempts at debugging, I've found that if you use `app(...)` in place of `App::make(...)` then the issue does not come up. I put in a [`eval(\Psy\sh())`](http://psysh.org/#usage) call in the `tearDown` of the `TestCase` class and found that after a few tests you get the following result:

```
>>> app()->bound('App\Contracts\OwnerInteractionInterface')
=> true
>>> App::bound('App\Contracts\OwnerInteractionInterface')
=> false
>>> App::getFacadeRoot() == app()           
=> false
```

This is to say that somehow, the `Laravel\Lumen\Application` instance that the `App` facade uses to resolve your objects is **not** the same as the current instance that is created by the `setUp()` method. I think that this instance is the old one from which all bindings have been cleared by a `$this->app->flush()` call in the `tearDown()` method so that it can't resolve any custom bindings in any tests that follow the first `tearDown()` call.

I've tried to hunt down the issue but for now I have to conclude this project with this workaround. I'll update this answer should I find the actual cause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `bind`, you can use `bindIf` method. Container will check whether the abstract has been bound or not. If not, it will bind your abstract and vice versa. You can read the api [here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Container/Container.html#method_bindIf).

So if you use `singleton`, you may use `bindIf` like.

```
// Owner manager
$this->app->bindIf(
    'App\Contracts\OwnerInteractionInterface',
    'App\Services\OwnerManager',
    true
);

// Subscriber manager
$this->app->bindIf(
    'App\Contracts\SubscriberInteractionInterface', 
    'App\Services\SubscriberManager',
    true
);
```

Comment: No dice it seems. I think that's basically what `singleton()` does behind the scenes.